# How do I add data property dynamically on component? (laravel)

Tags: laravel-5.3

My code is like this :

```
<div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2 class="nav-cat-text">By Types</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
        <div class="wrap-tabs">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-cat">
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                    <li role="presentation" class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="tab" @click="$refs.player.getPlayer({{ $category->id }})">{{ ucfirst($category->name) }}</a></li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active">
        <top-player-view category_id="1" ref="player"></top-player-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

category_id property in top-player-view is static

I want to make it more dynamic. So, I want category_id propery taken from category_id on first loop of $categories

How can I do it?

Comment: @Alexandru-Ionut Mihai, I seem to have found an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :
[I only typed the changed parts, you can understant.]

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
<li> ... </li>
@php
if ($loop->first)
$variable = $category->id
@endphp
@endforeach
...
<top-player-view category_id="{{ $variable }}" ref="player"></top-player-view>
```

Comment: There exist error `Undefined variable: variable (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\resources\views\front.blade.php)`

Comment: you need to change the variable name yourself.